# How to compile angular builds in a single index.html file that will be served from a http get request

Tags: angular, webpack

I am creating an angular project and want to serve it through an HTTP get request using AWS lambda.

So how to compile angular builds in a single index.html file so it would be easier to serve it through a lambda?

Comment: So what have you tried? Where is your code? Have you tried `ng build`? Have you searched anything through the Web? Although the question is somewhat on-topic, it is expected that you do some research before asking. Please do so next time.

Answer (score 0):

1 - Build your project using: **ng build --prod**

2 - Copy the content of the **dist** folder to your server.

3 - Configure the server to redirect requests for missing files to **index.html** using **htacess**